# I can't import gradle project Eclipse. "Finish" button does nothing

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am trying to import Gradle project to Eclipse. But it is impossible. Hitting "`finish`" button does nothing. I've already tried to import a few projects which are fine, because on another PC it just works with them. Also creating a new Gradle project does not work.

I have `gradle` installed, added `GRADLE_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME`, in `PATH` defined `%GRADLE_HOME%\bin` and `JAVA_HOME\bin`. Using `gradle` or `java` in command prompt works fine.

But here are screenshots with something weird: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tciD6.jpg
On default settings it does not work either.

Comment: Okay, so the problem was Java 9 which I had installed. After uninstalling it and installing JDK8 everything works good.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and I was able to get it working by upgrading the Buildship Gradle Integration plugin.

The version I had prior was 2.0 which doesn't support Java 9 but the 2.2 plugin does.

You can update it through eclipse in `Help > Eclipse Marketplace... > Installed > Update`. (I'm using Eclipse Oxygen)

Comment: This is stil happening in Eclipse JEE Photon, when using JDK11, using Buildship Gradle plugin 3.0. For the record it works well when using JDK9. The issue seems to be related to a poor initial config. If you find the Buildship Gradle plugin as described above, you can click on "Installed"; then, once the button changes to "Update" click on it again and wait for the update to finish. Finally restart Eclipse... and now everything works. Hope this trick helps.

Answer (score 1):

try this: import the project as a normal project (import > Existing Projects into Workspace), and then right click on the project and then click on "Configure" and then click on "Add Gradle Nature", summarizing (right click on the project > Configure > Add Gradle Nature)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
File => Launch Workspace => new Workspace...
=> Import project => next, next, next,... and Finish
```

I have tried & successful

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with two steps:

1. Right click on project > Configure > Convert to Faceted Form...
2. By default in Project Facets only Java is ticked. You need to also select Utility Mode

This enabled to finish gradle resolve.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your project directory different from the workspace if you don't already do it.
2. Delete the project from eclipse
3. Delete the `.classpath` and `.project` file from the directory
4. Make sure there are no other folder with same name (irrespective of case sensitivity)
5. Import the project again (Using - Import-> Existing gradle project)

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug in Eclipse that causes this behaviour.
The plugin showed me a previous installation directory that no longer existed and although it was disabled, it was checking for its existence.

No sure where it is being stored as I had also changed the general preferences...

**FIX: Go to Override Values and Change the Value to an existing directory**
The Finish button will unblock.